# R tree and Graph partitioning library in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, graph-theory, knn, r-tree

I need to make efficient d-dimensional points searching and also make efficient k-NN queries of a point in d-dimension. Therefore i require an R-Tree library. I require a library which will build the R-Tree structure, which i can use to query whenever needed.

Also i need to have some library like that of [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/metis/overview) or [hMETIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/metis/hmetis/overview), although my application does not involve hypergraphs. My requirement is to find the min cut set of a graph which divides the graph in roughly two equal sized graphs.

The thing is i would require libraries which support these in R.

I have found a library [RANN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RANN/index.html), which has kd-tree based k-NN queries, but the problem is that either i have to make all the k-NN queries at once and store the results in a huge array, or need to call the function (`nn` or `nn2`) every time i need, which defeates the O(n lg n) retrieval growth of time.

Can anyone tell me if there is any such libraries in R?

*Note:* I would require the R-Tree library for implementing clustering algorithms efficiently, and the graph partition library would be required to implement the CHAMELEON clustering algorithm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some study on R and its libraries i think it is better to get the required libraries or make my own code in C or C++ and then use it through the [.C()](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eC-and-_002eFortran) or [.Call()](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Interface-functions-_002eCall-and-_002eExternal) R to C language interface.

Comment: For implementation of Chameleon it's ok to use naive bisection using e.g. [Kernighan-Lin](http://www.r-bloggers.com/graph-bisection-in-r/).

Answer (score 0):

> Also i need to have some library like that of METIS or hMETIS, although my application does not involve hypergraphs. My requirement is to find the min cut set of a graph which divides the graph in roughly two equal sized graphs.

Despite that this is an old question, I have written something like this recently. That is,

1. A Kernighan-Lin like algorithm.
2. An algorithm to find an approximately connected balanced partition using the method suggested by Chlebíková (1996).
3. An algorithm that takes the solution found by the method in 2. and tries to minimize the cut price using a Kernighan-Lin like algorithm while still requiring that the two sets in the partition are connected.

From the graphs I am working with, 3. seems to often find a quite good solution often for bigger graphs (say ~ 1-4 million edges with ~ 1 million vertices). This takes seconds or a few minutes. The implementation is in the pedmod package at https://github.com/boennecd/pedmod. Call the following to install the package and to find a vignette with further details:

```r
remotes::install_github("boennecd/pedmod", build_vignettes = TRUE)
vignette("pedigree_partitioning", package = "pedmod")
```

I am not sure how my implementation compares in terms of speed and quality of the partition compared with other software though.

### References

Chlebíková, Janka. 1996. “Approximating the Maximally Balanced Connected Partition Problem in Graphs.” Information Processing Letters 60 (5): 225–30.

Kernighan, B. W., and S. Lin. 1970. “An Efficient Heuristic Procedure for Partitioning Graphs.” The Bell System Technical Journal 49 (2): 291–307